# Win RT phone 8.1: Unspecified Error while changing Device Orientation

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

I have a page in my app for OCR and when navigating to that page I change my orientation to landscape and when coming back i change it to portrait.

It was working fine before some days but now it is crashing stating only unspecified error. I started commenting my code and came to know that when this line of code is present my application crashes otherwise not.

```
DisplayInformation.AutoRotationPreferences = DisplayOrientations.Portrait;
```

I have two more pages with same functionality, same code is working on these pages. I know this is very little knowledge that I am providing but I even don't know what else I can provide. You can ask anything which can help.

Comment: Where is this line located (in constructor, in OnNavigatedTo method or somewhere else)?

Comment: it is on OnNavigatedTo

Comment: Have observed one more scenario, If I open OCR screen and scan a number it return to the screen and shows the number in my textbox and after that if I open OCR screen and then go back without scanning it doesn't crash. It crashes only if I open OCR for the first time and tap back button without scanning.